# ELisp function to org-todo current clocked task and keep current buffer still

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Image that I have a clocked task and I want clock-out it and set the heading to done the same time.Most importantly,I don't want to change my focus on my current buffer,I tried to write a function

```
(defun ql/done-current-clocked-task ()
  (interactive)
  (with-current-buffer
      (if (funcall 'org-clocking-p)
      (progn
        (org-clock-goto)
        (org-todo 'done))
    (message "No active clock!"))
    )
  )
```

But it failed to retutn to my original buffer but stop at the org file's buffer.I have no ideas.

Comment: What about `save-mark-and-excursion`?

Comment: I am not very familar with elisp but I figured out that I don't need to set it as a todo item because I just need to record it with clock and "TODO" keywords is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

I found it unneccessay to set the heading a TODO item as I just a heading item with clock-in and thus I don't need the function which clock-out it and org-todo